# Adding multiple tooltips for SVG nodes after button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to display the tooltips of multiple SVG nodes that have related properties based on a button click.

I have been following Scott Murrays book for creating tooltips, but that seems to work for having tooltips being displayed after a hover over event. My program is different in a sense that I want to press a button [Find related Titles] and have it display the tool tips for nodes that have the same title attribute.

Here is the div I created for tool Tips

```
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Important Label heading</strong></p>
    <p><span id="value">100</span>%</p>
</div>
```

Here is the style sheet:

```
#tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
}
```

This is how I create each node:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes).enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", function (d) { console.log("Represents: " + d.properties.represents); return "node "+ d.type.toString() })
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("fill", function(d) {return d.colr; })
        .call(force.drag);

// html title attribute
node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
```

Now when a node is clicked, the program generates buttons for finding nodes that have the same properties. **Here we are just trying to set up tooltips for when the findTitlesBtn is pressed.**

```
node.on("click", function(n)
                {
                /// Several more lines of code ///
                    getTitle = n.properties.title;

                    //Dynamically create button for finding related Titles
                    if (getTitle !== undefined) {
                        //Create the button element
                        var findTitlesBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 

                        //Create the button label, and add it to the button
                        var title = document.createTextNode("Find Related Titles");      
                        findTitlesBtn.appendChild(title);

                        //Call findTitle function when button is clicked
                        findTitlesBtn.onclick = findTitle;

                        //Add button to the 'displayOptions' div inside the console
                        document.getElementById("displayOptions").appendChild(findTitlesBtn);
                    }
```

And Finally, the function called when the button is clicked. I believe it should be in this function. After I filter through the nodes (based on if they have the same title attribute) each one will call a function that makes their tooltip visible. **The nodes that are filtered are the ones I want to display a tooltip.**

```
//Function used to find nodes with related 'Title' properties
    function findTitle() {

        //Return color of nodes back to normal
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

        //Filter through all nodes to find matching titles, color them yellow
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.title == getTitle; })
        .style('fill', 'yellow')
        .onload = function(d) {

            //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"));

            //Update the tooltip position and value
            d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("left", xPosition + "px")
            .style("top", yPosition + "px")
            .select("#value")
            .text(d);

            //Show the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
        }
    }
```

This is not working however. I cant find anything online related to this specific problem or documentation for what I'm trying to do. I have minor experience with Javascript and its the first time I've used SVG/D3. Any suggestions on what is wrong with my current implementation would be greatly appreciated! While I've added all relevant parts of code above, I've attached the full script below for completeness.

Here is the full source code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="console">
<h2>Find all matches:</h3>
<div id="displayOptions"></div>

<div id="metainfo"></div>
</div>

<div id="graph">
</div>

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Important Label heading</strong></p>
    <p><span id="value">100</span>%</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .node { stroke: #222; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
    .node.Column { fill: #777; }
    .node.Table { fill: #BBB; }
    .node.JoinTable { fill: #999}
    .node.Dataset { fill: #333}
    .link { stroke: #999; stroke-width: 7px; }
    div {height: 100%;}
    html {height: 100%;}
    body {height: 100%;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 1200, height = 800, radius = 20;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-1000).linkDistance(150).size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%")
            .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    //var currRepresents = "null";



    d3.json("/Justin/graph", function(error, graph) {
        if (error) return;

        force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links).enter()
                .append("line").attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes).enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { console.log("Represents: " + d.properties.represents); return "node "+ d.type.toString() })
                .attr("r", radius)
                .style("fill", function(d) {return d.colr; })
                .call(force.drag);

        // html title attribute
        node.append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; })


        var state = false;
        var last = null;
        var current = null;
        node.on("click", function(n)
                {
                    //Return color of nodes back to normal
                    svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

                    //Remove buttons from previous mouse click
                    var getOptionsDiv = document.getElementById("displayOptions");
                    while (getOptionsDiv.hasChildNodes()) { 
                        getOptionsDiv.removeChild(getOptionsDiv.lastChild);
                    }


                    //Get Represents property from currently selected node
                    currRepresents = n.properties.represents;

                    //Add data to meta info div
                    var metainf = "";
                    metainf = metainf.concat("Title: ", n.name, "<br/>Label: ", n.type, "<br/>Represents: ", n.properties.represents, 
                    "<br/>Column Type: ", n.properties.columntype, "<br/>Semantic Relation: ", n.properties.semanticrelation);
                    console.log(metainf);
                    d3.select("#metainfo")
                        .html(metainf);

                    last = current;
                    current = d3.select(this);
                    current.style('fill', 'red');
                    last.style('fill', function(d) { return d.colr; });

                    getTitle = n.properties.title;
                    getRepresents = n.properties.represents;
                    getColumnType = n.properties.columntype;
                    getSemanticRelation = n.properties.semanticrelation;

                    //Dynamically create button for finding related Titles
                    if (getTitle !== undefined) {
                        //Create the button element
                        var findTitlesBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 

                        //Create the button label, and add it to the button
                        var title = document.createTextNode("Find Related Titles");      
                        findTitlesBtn.appendChild(title);

                        //Call findTitle function when button is clicked
                        findTitlesBtn.onclick = findTitle;

                        //Add button to the 'displayOptions' div inside the console
                        document.getElementById("displayOptions").appendChild(findTitlesBtn);
                    }

                    //Dynamically create button for finding related Represents
                    if (getRepresents !== undefined) {
                        //Create the button element
                        var findRepresentsBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

                        //Create the button label, and add it to the button 
                        var title = document.createTextNode("Find Related Represents");       
                        findRepresentsBtn.appendChild(title);

                        //Call findRepresents function when button is clicked
                        findRepresentsBtn.onclick = findRep;

                        //Add button to the 'displayOptions' div inside the console
                        document.getElementById("displayOptions").appendChild(findRepresentsBtn);
                    }

                    //Dynamically create button for finding related Column Types
                    if (getColumnType !== undefined) {
                        //Create the button element
                        var findColumnTypeBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 

                        //Create the button label, and it to the button
                        var title = document.createTextNode("Find Related Column Types");       
                        findColumnTypeBtn.appendChild(title);

                        //Call findColType function when button is clicked
                        findColumnTypeBtn.onclick = findColType;

                        //Add button to the 'displayOptions' div inside the console
                        document.getElementById("displayOptions").appendChild(findColumnTypeBtn);
                    }

                    //Dynamically create button for finding related Semantic Relations
                    if (getSemanticRelation !== undefined) {
                        //Create the button element
                        var findSemanticRelationsBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 

                        //Create the button label, and it to the button
                        var title = document.createTextNode("Find Related Semantic Relations");       
                        findSemanticRelationsBtn.appendChild(title);

                        //Call findSemRel function when button is clicked
                        findSemanticRelationsBtn.onclick = findSemRel;

                        //Add button to the 'displayOptions' div inside the console
                        document.getElementById("displayOptions").appendChild(findSemanticRelationsBtn);
                    }



                });



        // force feed algo ticks
        force.on("tick", function() {

             node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
             .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });


            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });



    });

    function findRepresents() {
        if (currRepresents == "null") {
            console.log("No node is clicked on currently!");
        } else {
            console.log(currRepresents);
        }

    }

    //Function used to find nodes with related 'Title' properties
    function findTitle() {

        //Return color of nodes back to normal
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

        //Filter through all nodes to find matching titles, color them yellow
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.title == getTitle; })
        .style('fill', 'yellow')
        .onload = function(d) {

            //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"));

            //Update the tooltip position and value
            d3.select("#tooltip")
            .style("left", xPosition + "px")
            .style("top", yPosition + "px")
            .select("#value")
            .text(d);

            //Show the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
        }
    }

    //Function used to find nodes with related 'Represents' properties
    function findRep() {      

        //Return color of nodes back to normal
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

        //Filter through all nodes to find matching represents, color them blue
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.represents == getRepresents; })
        .style('fill', 'blue');

    }

    //Function used to find nodes with related 'Column Type' properties
    function findColType() {        

        //Return color of nodes back to normal
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

        //Filter through all nodes to find matching column types, color them green
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.columntype == getColumnType; })
        .style('fill', 'green');

    }

    //Function used to find nodes with related 'Semantic Relation' properties
    function findSemRel() {     

        //Return color of nodes back to normal
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

        //Filter through all nodes to find matching semantic relations, color them orange
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.semanticrelation == getSemanticRelation; })
        .style('fill', 'orange');

    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the Java code that creates the JSON:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, Object> graph(int limit) {

        Iterator<Map<String,Object>> result = cypher.query(
                "match (c)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p) " +
                "return c.title as childName, labels(c) as childType, ID(c) as childId, c as child, p.title as parentName, labels(p) as parentType, ID(p) as parentId, p as parent ", 
                map("1",limit));

         List nodes = new ArrayList();
         List rels= new ArrayList();

         int i = 0;
         //Iterate through each row of the resulting cypher query
         while (result.hasNext()) 
         {

            //Row has a dataset, a table, and a collection of columns
            Map<String, Object> row = result.next();

            //Add the child node if it is not already there
            Map<String, Object> childNode = map("id", row.get("childId"), "name", row.get("childName"), "type", row.get("childType"), "properties", row.get("child"));
            int source = nodes.indexOf(childNode);
            if (source == -1) 
            {
                nodes.add(childNode);
                source = i++;
            }

            //Add the parent node if it is not already there
            Map<String, Object> parentNode = map("id", row.get("parentId"), "name", row.get("parentName"), "type", row.get("parentType"), "properties", row.get("parent"));
            int target = nodes.indexOf(parentNode);
            if (target == -1) 
            {
                nodes.add(parentNode);
                target = i++;
            }

            rels.add(map("source", source, "target", target));

         }
         return map("nodes", nodes, "links", rels);

     }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your json returned from `/Justin/graph`?  It's hard to wade through the code without seeing it run...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Mark, I have just added the Java code that creates the json. Let me know if this clarifies things a bit, and thanks for your time and help!